# Beginner getting ValueError

Tags: python, string, random, getopt, valueerror

I'm a beginner coder on python trying to make a "die roller" where you can choose the size of die and it returns this error on my 20th line of my code

```
import sys
import random
import getopt


def main(argv):
    dsize = ''
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "hi:o:", ["dsize="])
        except getopt.GetoptError:
        print("Roll.py -d <dsize>")
        sys.exit(2)
    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt == '-h':
            print('Roll.py -d <dsize>')
            sys.exit()
            # elif opt in ("-d", "--dsize"):
            #  dsize = arg
    print('Die size is ', dsize)
    print('roll is: '(random.randrange(1, dsize)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

also if i uncomment the "elif opt in", and "dsize" i get this

```
 File "h:\Projects\Roll.py", line 17
   elif opt in ("-d", "--dsize"):
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What exactly does the error say?

Comment: The code you posted and your error don't match - the `elif` is commented out in your code but in the error it's now executed? Also, double check the indentation matches (eg: the `except` should be one level less)

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably on this line:

```
print('roll is: '(random.randrange(1, dsize)))
```

You're trying to concatenate a string and an integer. There are two options:

```
print('roll is: ', random.randrange(1, dsize))
```

Or

```
print('roll is: ' + str(random.randrange(1, dsize)))
```

Answer (score 0):

OR change:

```
print('roll is: '(random.randrange(1, dsize)))
```

To:

```
print('roll is: {}'.format(random.randrange(1, dsize)))
```

Or:

```
print('roll is: %s'%random.randrange(1, dsize))
```

Or the new f-strings (only works with python version > 3.6):

```
print(f'roll is: {random.randrange(1, dsize)}')
```

Full code:

```
import sys
import random
import getopt


def main(argv):
    dsize = ''
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "hi:o:", ["dsize="])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        print("Roll.py -d <dsize>")
        sys.exit(2)
    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt == '-h':
            print('Roll.py -d <dsize>')
            sys.exit()
            # elif opt in ("-d", "--dsize"):
            #  dsize = arg
    print('Die size is ', dsize)
    print('roll is: {}'.format(random.randrange(1, dsize))) # here i just use the first option


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error appears to be caused by the indentation level of your `elif` line. The conditional statement should be formatted like this:

```
if opt == '-h':
    print('Roll.py -d <dsize>')
    sys.exit()
elif opt in ("-d", "--dsize"):
    dsize = arg
```

Here's a link that has some example of conditional statement in python: [Flow Control in Python](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1312792&seqNum=3)

Answer (score 0):

In the line 8, There is error due to not correct indentation.

```
try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "hd:", ["dsize="])
except getopt.GetoptError:
    print("Roll.py -d <dsize>")
    sys.exit(2)
```

Answer (score -2):

The issue is because you are trying to find an element that is a different type then the type that you want to find it. An example of this would be trying to find an int type in an existing string type.

A solution would be to just make your int into string.